# CSS: How to center element that is bigger then the container?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have element that have 800px and the container is smaller (it's responsive so the width is changing), I have code like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="popup">
   </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#container { width: 400px; position: relative; }
#popup { width: 800px; position: absolute; }
```

I've try `left: 0, right: 0, margin: auto;` but it don't work the box is aligned to the left.

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/popecefe/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Why not changing the `width` of `popup` to 100%?

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/popecefe/4/) ?

Comment: @enyce12 because I want larger popup not equal.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/popecefe/5/ you should remove the dialog-box from the  container.

Comment: @Rotherford I need it inside because I want to position it relative to the container.

Comment: @PatsyIssa add this as an answer.

Comment: well, problem is that the children are clipped to their parents. thus aligning them at center is not possible. You can , in fact, use scrolling..

Comment: @Rotherford PatsyIssa answer work. Children are not clipped unless you use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Just a test to make both the elements responsive.. [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/popecefe/18/).. did after referring patsyIssa's solution.

Comment: No need, it's already been answered all across SO ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin-left: -(half width)px` and `left: 50%`

so your code popup css code will look like:

```
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #0a0;
  height: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `#popup{position: relative;top: 50%;}` and align it with `top: ((div height / 2) - popup height)` i.e. `top: 130px`

Comment: I want to center it horizontaly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc function.

left:calc(50% - 200px); // 50% - (width of popup/2)

http://caniuse.com/calc (check compatibility with all devices and browsers)

```
#container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
}
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px; // width of popup
  background-color: #0a0;
  height: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  left:calc(50% - 200px); // 50% - (width of popup/2)
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

In above case width of popup is 400px. We have to align popup in center so we will use left:50%.
This will align popup's y position to center. Now we have to minus half width of popup to make it center.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you change the left and right values to -25% it should work.

```
#popup {
    left: -25%;
    right: -25%;
}
```

Comment: That will not work if the popup box is bigger that 300px

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for the comment, I was just about to accept that answer.